# Any criterion to numerically check the orthogonality between two noisy vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^\top$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=(y_1,\dots,y_n)^\top$ are two standardized vectors, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0$ and $\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}=1$, is there any method to numerically judge $\boldsymbol{x}\perp \boldsymbol{y}$?

Actually $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are two observed noisy data vectors, so I think it is not appropriate to use $\boldsymbol{x}^\top \boldsymbol{y}=0$ as the criterion.

Comment: Noisy vectors? I got to remember that one.:)

Comment: Two vectors are either orthogonal or they are not. If you whish to enlarge the concept of "orthogonality" you may want to add some tolerance and test for x'y smaller than some very small value. What I believe you are looking for is a criterion for establishing the orthogonality of the distributions of x and y... but that's really dependent on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

We measure, or compute, noisy vectors. Consider the case of $m$ vectors. Hoping for
$$
x = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  x_{1} \\ \vdots \\x_{m}
\end{array} \right], \quad
%
y = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  y_{1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{m}
\end{array} \right]
$$
we instead measure or compute
$$
x = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  x_{1} + \epsilon_{1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{m} + \epsilon_{m}
\end{array} \right], \quad
%
y = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  y_{1} + \delta_{1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{m} + \delta_{m}
\end{array} \right]
$$
To make progress, consider the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ terms to come from distributions with $0$ mean. Further assume the distribution of errors is random.

Noise is inevitable. How big are $\epsilon$ and $\delta$? How much noise is in the data? Did we spend a lot of money and build a measurement apparatus with great fidelity? Are the computations to produce these data based on ill-conditioned systems or ill-posed differential equations?

The object of study is not
$$ 
  x^{*} y = x \cdot y = \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k} \bar{y}_{k} = 0.
$$
The object of study is instead how 
$$ 
  \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k} \bar{y}_{k} - 
  \sum_{k=1}^{m} 
  \left( x_{k} + \epsilon_{k} \right) 
  \left( \bar{y}_{k} + \delta_{k} \right),
\tag{1}
$$
a number which is $0$ on the blackboard and nonzero in computation.

---

To first order (that is, ignoring terms like $\epsilon \delta$), the error is 
$$ 
  \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k} \bar{y}_{k} - 
  \sum_{k=1}^{m} 
  \left( x_{k} + \epsilon_{k} \right) 
  \left( \bar{y}_{k} + \delta_{k} \right)
%
=
\sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k} \delta_{k} + \bar{y}_{k} \epsilon_{k}
$$
In practice, you will set a threshold value for numeric $0$. This is the standard problem that arises with real numbers in finite precision representation: don't check $x-y=0$, check $\lvert x - y \rvert < \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is set by a linear combination of insight and hope.